# Showing sequence for 2 giving convergent sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let there be 2 sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$. They both converge to $L$. Show that sequence $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...)$ also converges to $L$. It is the question and I related this sequence with $c_n$. Then I compose a new sequence as $c_{2n-1}=a_n , c_{2n}= b_n$. Now, what do I suppose to do?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary.

Since $a_n$ is convergent, $\exists n_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \ge n_1 \Rightarrow |a_n-L| \lt \epsilon$.

Similarly, for $b_n$, $\exists n_2 \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \ge n_2 \Rightarrow |b_n-L| \lt \epsilon.$

Now as you have taken $c_{2n-1}=a_n$ and $c_{2n}=b_n$, substitute them above to get,

$|c_{2n-1}-L| \lt \epsilon \; \forall \; n \ge n_1$ & $|c_{2n}-L| \lt \epsilon \; \forall \; n \ge n_2$.

Take $n_3=\max\{2n_1 - 1, 2n_2\}$.

Then for $n \ge n_3$, we get $|c_n-L| \lt \epsilon$. Which means $c_n$ converges to $L$.